# Creating this Custom, Reusable View

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I need to create a custom, reusable view component. I've been trying to look around to see how exactly custom views in android are created. But I'm a little confused.

I need an example or an explanation of the steps I need to take in order to make this happen.

What I need in my view is the following: two `TextView` and two `Button`, which already have their functionality programmed. The button should increment or decrease an `int` which is displayed on the `Quantity TextView`.

```
|----------------------------------------------------------------|
|                                                                |
| Name of Item --- Quantity --- (Button Minus) --- (Button Plus) |
|                                                                |
|----------------------------------------------------------------|
```

Therefore, I would get this component by calling something like `MyComp mc = new MyComp()` and would get the values as normal (`mc.getName`, `mc.getQty`)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please view the android documentation regarding [CompoundControls](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/custom-components.html#compound).

Comment: So I would want to extend LinearLayout and programatically add the buttons / textviews?

Comment: You can, but it's better to define the layout in xml. You can take a look at this app that I've made that has a realitvely simple example. Checkout the ClockView class. https://github.com/klnusbaum/Link-Schedule/blob/master/src/org/klnusbaum/linkschedule/ClockView.java

Comment: But if I define it using XML, that means the `qty` TextView will not be unique for each new one....right?

Comment: Each one will have it's own `qty` text view.